# Convert seconds since epoch to a human readable string

Tags: command-line, scripts, date

Command `date +%s` produces `1403568422`. Is there an easy way to convert the `1403568422` to a human readable UTC timestamp?

`python -c "import datetime;print datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1403568422).isoformat()"` kind of works; I can also write a short C program to do the same thing. Is there a better way?

**Clarification**

I do not want to make date print the current time in UTC. I want date (or other utility) to convert a given number of seconds since UTC - say 1403568422 - to a human readable format.

Background: I have these timestamps in a file and I wanted to know when exactly the things happened.

Comment: There are so many web pages giving you this answer... `date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S`
Please have a look around before you keep repeating the same questions. There's also something called `man date` or `info date`

Comment: Uh, `date` can print whatever time you want it to. From `man date`:
`-d, --date=STRING    display time described by STRING, not 'now'`. 
Huh, there's even an example in the man page dealing with exactly this conversion.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for pointing to the example. Although that is the only place where @ is mentioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for this,

```
date -d @$(date +%s) +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

It changes the seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC to a human-readable string.

**Example:**

```
$ date -d @$(date +%s) +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2014-06-24 06:06:54
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11021491/3297613)

Comment: `date -d @1403568422   +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` was what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `date -d @seconds` :

`date -d @1403568422` :

```
$ date -d @1403568422 
Mon Jun 23 19:07:02 CDT 2014
```

Comment: Isn't this simpler than the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/487356/24203)?